# Clang Link Time Optimization doesn't work with arm-none-eabi-gcc toolchain

Tags: c, gcc, linker, arm, clang

I'm working with an STM32F3 series ARM processor and trying to get clang compilation to work. I already have arm-none-ambi-gcc compiling properly with link time optimizations.

I am able to get clang to compile only if I disable link time optimization (don't include `-flto` in compiler flags). From what I've found on the internet, this is because arm-none-ambi-gcc toolchain doesn't have a [gold linker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gold_(linker)) (`ld.gold`) and clang apparently needs this to do `lto` ([link](https://github.com/android-ndk/ndk/issues/242)). Unfortunately, it sounds like the arm-none-eabi-gcc toolchain isn't planing on ever supporting this ([forum post here](https://answers.launchpad.net/gcc-arm-embedded/+question/354098))

When I compile only using arm-none-eabi-gcc, it can use link time optimization no problem without a gold linker. Is there a way to get link time optimization with clang ***without*** a gold linker?

Comment: didnt know you could cross link with llvm, compile sure, link thought that was only for the native host platform.  I use clang to bytecode to object then use binutils for linking.  used to assemble as well but llvm now has an object output from llc.  your link shows that gnu has had gold since 2.18 we are now at 2.28. gcc does not have an assembler nor a linker it is just a compiler, it relies on binutils to assemble and link programs.

Comment: as pointed out by the llvm folks you can use opt instead, I like that approach as you can optimize across the whole project rather than per file.  what the description of lto is doing.

Comment: you can use qemu or buy a raspberry pi or other and use a native clang with whatever linker it provides (if it has a native one) and not have to cross compile/cross link.

Comment: last time I tried sadly even with whole project optimization, gcc was producing smaller and/or faster code.  Granted llvm was getting better and gcc has been on a slide toward the worse, so perhaps one has passed the other.  It is extremely specific to the application though as to what the differences in size or performance are between the tools.  One isnt automatically better simply because they have a command line switch.

Comment: sadly llvm/clang provide too many tools, you can optimize on each step, single file, then the project then the backend.  the combinations start to get unmanageable as the number of files in the project increases, seems to reason and last time I tried not optimizing during compiling gave opt more to chew on, but again the combinations are too many to try.  and benchmarking is always bulls..t as it is so easy to manipulate the results, even using your application, or machine code output of an object, can still change performance without modification to that machine code...

Comment: ...can manipulate the performance, so benchmarking only gets you so far, examining the code only gets you so far, counting instructions (I wrote a thumb simulator just to compare these two tools) only gets you so far.

Comment: I stopped supporting clang/llvm in my makefiles as every version that comes out the command line options I rely on to do these optimizations, changes, and I have to revisit makefiles and make them clang/llvm version specific, where the gcc portion of the makefile can remain unchanged for going on years now.

Comment: Thanks for all of the insight. I've also noticed that gcc is producing smaller bin size compared to llvm given the same arguments. I'll give the llvm byte code route a try too

Comment: interesting thing I have experienced with compile for size vs speed on at least one compiler the compile for speed was smaller than compile for size, go figure.  so I would recommend trying that as well even if size is your ultimate goal.